# Airflow: How can I access {{ execution date }} on my custom operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I built a custom operator on Airflow that calls an API to fetch data and then write it to BigQuery. However, the issue is that I have to pass the execution_date macro as an API param to be able to call the data for that date. Sadly, when I tried doing this my operator is not able to parse the jinja template I passed. When I checked the logging I made for this it shows only the template as seen in the image below.
I hope you guys can help.

[Airflow Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blwoX.png)

This is my code for the custom operator and the dag. Thanks!

```
                 ...
class MyOperator(BaseOperator):

     def __init__(self,date):
          super(MyOperator,self).__init__(*arg,**kwargs)

          self.date = date

     def __pull_from_api(self):
          api_link = "somelink.com/api/date={}".format(self.date)
          data = request.get(api_link).json()
          return data

     def execute(self,context):
          data = self.__pull_from_api()

                 ...


dag = DAG('My Pipeline', default_args=default_args)

t1 = MyOperator(date='{{ execution_date}}', task_id='my_pipeline_1', dag=dag)
t1
```

Comment: Did you follow the Jinja Templating instructions to check if your template is ok? Because, according to the documentation you should be able to pass a macro reference to execution_date to pass it. LINKS:  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros.html#default-variables and https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#id1

Comment: Yes I have. I placed it under the ```template_fields``` variable as recommended. Yet, the same situation still happens.

Comment: If you set it up correctly it should be able to pass the exeution_date, I am investigating it. Meanwhile, I saw the documentation and I was wondering if you had a look at PythonOperator to access the execution_date or even the context dict? Links: https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-guides/blob/master/guides/templating.md and https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/python.html

Comment: Furthermore, can you elaborate on why you can not pass the execution_date using the jinja template?

Comment: It has been fixed. I followed the first link on your second comment (https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-guides/blob/master/guides/templating.md) as a guideline for my code. Used a tuple instead of a list for **template_fields** like this ```template_fields = ('execution_date','var')```. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am glad I could help. I made the comment which helped you as an answer for this question, I would appreciate if you can accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encourage you to have a look at the [PythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/python.html) and [context dictionary](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html). Both  are useful when working with variables in Composer.

Firstly, since you already have your custom operator I strongly recommend you to have a look [here](https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-guides/blob/master/guides/templating.md). There are some common Macros and templates using Airflow. Therefore, you can find out where you might have a misstep.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to get execution_date from context, which is already passed to execute(self,context).

For example, here i am setting string representation of an execution date :

```
self.execution_date_str = context["execution_date"].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

[Example in LatestOnlyOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/latest_only_operator.py#L53-L54)